# using R to run a formula

Tags: r, formula

I am new to R and want to apply this formula in standard R. it works fine when i put the value for OR and P.
SE<-abs(log(OR)/qnorm(P/2))

however instead of actual value, I want to first upload a file that has a column of OR and P (header) for many.
i try this:

`mydata <- read.csv("myfile", header=TRUE, sep="\t") SE<-abs(log(OR)/qnorm(P/2)) write.csv (SE, file="SEtest")`

it gives error that object OR is not found. appreciate helps!

Comment: either use `attach(mydata)` or replace OR and P by `mydata$OR` and `mydata$P`

Comment: I add this but got another error:

Comment: > SE<-abs(log(mydata$OR)/qnorm(mydata$P/2))
Error in log(mydata$OR) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: Apparently `mydata$OR` is character data. What does `str(mydata)` show?

Comment: the file is big: str(mydata)  'data.frame':   8053394 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ CHR..........BP............SNP..A1..A2...N...........P........P.R.......OR...